# Answers and solutions

Tags: discussion, self-answer

How come I have to wait two days to answer my own question? That doesn't make sense. If anyone figures out the answer to their own question, it is best resolved by THEIR OWN ANSWER. It seems like that should shoot to the top of the stack, rather than wait down below... I would prepend that the best way to thread an answer is take whatever seems like the first applicable solution and than judging it based on it's ratings... not denying a users self solution for two days. That solution should be posted and than judged! No one (essentially) is going to bother judging an unconfirmed solution.

Comment: Nice question, to be asked in meta.

Comment: Wait, what? You can't **accept** your own answer for two days. You can post an answer to your own question immediately. Literally. You can type the question and answer at the same time and post them together!

Comment: I appreciate your responses, but did I deserve a down-merit for being new to the community? I'd rather have an explanation as to why that was a question I should pose to another community/site rather than a straight dismissal. Seems kinda childish.

Comment: @JonathanCrawford what down merit are you talking about?

Comment: lost 2 stackoverflow merit points based on other users reviews, and there's no way to revoke/challenge them since the thread has been migrated.

Comment: Small potatoes really, Jonathan. You asked in the wrong place, and someone dinged you for that. Move on; you'll make it back in 1/5 of an answer.

Comment: Jonathan, the "Ask a Question" page on SO has this in the sidebar: "If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead." (with a link). So you could have found this out yourself before posting. (As for the question stub left over on SO, it'll disappear after a while.)

Comment: @animuson You actually need 15 reputation to self-answer immediately, and users with less than 100 reputation have to wait 8 hours before self-answering the normal way (unless it's since been changed, but I don't think so)

Comment: @TimStone: Really? I guess I've never noticed since those things aren't mentioned in the reputation section of the FAQ. I'll just assume it's mentioned in the privileges wikis somewhere. If not, there's a problem.

Comment: @JonathanCrawford: `did I deserve a down-merit for being new to the community?` .. have you read the FAQ (link to it is in site-header) on what questions to ask and not to ask on the stackoverflow site (before it was migrated) which is for members who are new to the community? http://stackoverflow.com/faq Anyways, +1 for good question on meta.

Comment: @animuson: it's documented in the "Edit community wiki" (wtf?) priv. page - http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki; but that seems obsolete since Jonathan posted his answer 1h after his question and is below that threshold.

Comment: @Mat Hmm, it's possible that the limit was reduced to 15 to be inline with the limit for immediately self-answering. I seem to vaguely recall a discussion about that...

Comment: OK; I give in. I guess I'm not fully up on the FAQ. Just seemed to me like I was asking a legitimate question that the community should answer; not the facilitator. I didn't want to know how stackoverflow handled it; I wanted the community to fill me in. But I acquiesce; I'll check up on the FAQ before I complain again. Thank YOU! Everyone who participated, I was in the wrong, and thank you for your participants.

Answer (score 3):

I am confused! You are saying that you can figure it out in two days. If you are so confident in figuring it out then why to ask it? Some times you do find solution in less than two days but you don't expect it to be solved so easily so you should wait for two days. If the time limit will be removed than this site will loose its charm. It will be more like a quiz. Questioner will ask question and will give the answer. So its good to have such restrictions.

Comment: Lol it's called a deadline. I didn't know that I would figure out an answer to my question. I'm glad I did. But isn't that why these communities are here? To help in case of emergence?

Comment: No.[‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Right. We reach out to get answers from others who have facility in this field. Or not, as you say. Derp.

Comment: @JonathanCrawford: There is a bigger picture. The way I see it is that members in the community give up their own free time to help out if they can because they like learning, passing on what they learned and together help creating a collection of knowledge hopefully useful to not only you or your case of emergency but also for any future user who may have a similar issue. To that end; `No` the community is not here to serve only ones case of emergency.

Comment: But why in that context does helping people who need solutions quickly wrong? Since I could, in the end, help myself, why should the community be denied an answer to my question more quickly? One that could have possibly helped someone else in the interim 48 hours. But again, I acquiesce to the knowledge that I asked a question in the wrong place. Like perhaps I should have been able to accept my own answer within the 48 hours, but only be accepted by stack after review from another member of the community or until 48 hours were up?

Comment: Nope. There is nothing wrong expecting solution quickly. Most of the answers comes in with in minutes provided you ask a good question and provide complete details. If you think you can answer you question then definitely you will use some other resource. So why don't you try to your best then come to this site? When you will feel I am done I cant solve it then come here and ask.